# Issue when trying to recursively open sub-directories in C

Tags: c, recursion, directory

I'm working on an assignment that will list the directories in the current directory (.) and will recursively open sub-directories and print out their file contents.

I'm having this weird issue, where my sub-directories open up, but then for some reason, instead of trying to print the file contents in those sub-directories, it takes each file inside the sub-directory and tries to open it as a directory, leading to errors.

For example, if I do: `$ ./ls .`

My output should look like (note that `.` is my current directory):

```
.
    file_name.c
    file_2.c
    sub_directory_1
        file_3.c
    sub_directory_2
        main.c
        test.c
    file_4.c
```

Instead, I'm getting this as my output:

```
.
    file_name.c
    file_2.c
    sub_directory_1
        Error while opening directory file_3.c: No such file or directory
    sub_directory_2
        Error while opening directory main.c: No such file or directory
        Error while opening directory test.c: No such file or directory
    file_4.c
```

Here is my current recursive method. I just don't understand why it will print out files in the current directory, but not entries in the subdirectories..

```
void ls_directory(char *dir_name, int level)
{
    DIR *p_dir = NULL; // pointer to a directory
    struct dirent *p_entry; // pointer to a directory entry
    if(!(p_dir = opendir(dir_name)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening directory %s: %s\n", dir_name, strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    printf("%s\n", dir_name);
    while((p_entry = readdir(p_dir)))
    {
        if(is_dir(p_entry->d_name) == DIRECTORY)
        {
            // do not list the parent directories
            if(strcmp(p_entry->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(p_entry->d_name, "..") != 0){
                ls_directory(p_entry->d_name, level + 1);
            }
        } else {
            ls_file(p_entry->d_name);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    closedir(p_dir);
}
```

Note that `ls_file()` just prints out statements. And the code for `is_dir()` just checks to see if it is a directory, and returns a predefined value if it is, or 0 if it isn't.

```
int is_dir(char *file_name)
{
    stat(file_name, &sb);
    if(S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
        return DIRECTORY;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: last I checked `opendir` nor `stat` both should require a name in the current working directory or a full path. Your recursion provides neither.

Comment: @WhozCraig Are you saying that both `stat` and `opendir` do not require a directory name for checking? Or are you saying that both of them require a working directory or full path?

Comment: No I'm saying when you run it from a given working directory, any directories you recurse into need to be *preambled* to the `d_name` before checking with a proper separator. A full path would work, but unless you kick things off with `getcwd` that isn't really feasible.

Comment: Put it another way. Once you recurse for `sub_directory_1` and you `opendir` you'll get `file_3.c` in the list, but `file_3.c` isn't in the *current* working directory, so a call to `stat(file_3.c)` is going to fail. The same goes for any subs dirs. Either you need to build the path or `setcwd` going in, and revert coming back out, of each recursion. I hope that was clearer.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think I understand what you are saying. I think I need to have the stat buffer in the recursive method so that I can build a correct path..

Comment: @WhozCraig Do I build the path before I check if the entry is a directory or after when I check if the entry is a directory? I tried doing a simple `strcpy` to a temp string, then doing `strcat("/");` on the `temp` string, then doing `strcat` with the entry, and finally recursing with that.. but I got the same error.

Comment: Because your directory check uses `stat`, yes, you need the built path. sorry if I left that out. Remember, each element returned from `reader` is relative to the path passed to `opendir` if you want to `stat` it, it needs that path or `stat` won't know where to find it. [example](http://pastebin.com/Nb0uUzbW). Again, sorry I left that out. That should unroll a full path for you now.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you, looking at the example makes a lot more sense now.